# Cant seem to get regex.search to return anything

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to retrieve a string if it contains "_XXXX" at the end of the string.

Here is my code

```
import re
string = "45263462346wefw_XLey"
print(re.search(string, r"_[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\Z"))
```

This returns None, I am obviously doing something wrong but I cannot figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `{}` you can chose the number of occurence you want. So `"_[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\Z"` become `"_[a-zA-Z]{4}\Z"`. 
So if you have different number of letter you can do `"_[a-zA-Z]{1,4}\Z"` to match between 1 and 4 letters.

And `re.search()` takes `pattern` before `string` :

```
import re
string = "45263462346wefw_XLey"

print(re.search(r"_[a-zA-Z]{4}\Z", string))


print(re.findall(r"_[a-zA-Z]{4}\Z", string))
```

output :

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(15, 20), match='_XLey'>
['_XLey']
```